# Error in setting up Android usb debugging in ubuntu 14.10

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, udev, usb-debugging

I have a android phone from LG, and I want to use it for USB debugging. I followed the following steps:

```
1. Enabled usb debugging in developers option on phone.

2. After connecting to PC, phone shows as "Usb debugging connected". I verified the same by command "lsusb" on Ubuntu 14.10. It shows following result:

   Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1004:633e LG Electronics, Inc.

3. Then I followed steps given in https://developer.android.com, to setup hardware device.

   Log in as root and create this file: /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules.

   Use this format to add each vendor to the file: SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

   Now execute: chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

4. After that I rebooted the computer.

5. Now when I try to check device list in adb by command "./adb devices" , It does not show device listed.
```

Can anybody please help? Kindly let me know where I am doing wrong.. Thanks

Comment: double check your edit in /etc/udev and make sure to use the connector cable from the LG device ( not some random usb connect )

Comment: Use lsusb to find out the actual vid of the device.  Make sure it is in your rules file and also in you adb ini file in your ~/.android directory

Comment: Close voters: development tool questions are *explicitly* on topic, and the question details *exactly* what has been tried.

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/the-most-comprehensive-write-up-on-how.html

Answer (score -1):

I found this guid fixed my issue.  I was facing the same thing when trying to connect to an Azpen A1023

http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/888